# API Timeout error with HttpWebRequest C# | wroking with postman and restsharp

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, httpwebrequest

I am trying to make apiAPI(Expedia API for Hotel booking) with URL [https://test.ean.com/2.1/itineraries?token=](https://test.ean.com/2.1/itineraries?token) using C# HttpWebRequest and every time its return time out error

I'm trying to send request using RestSharp some time it works , when I use PostMan or soap UI there are no problem but when I do it with code using HttpWebRequest I got error like

```
{"The operation has timed out"}
```

I am using below header to execute API

```
Accept-Encoding gzip
Authorization EAN apikey=3dsc5rp4ae3hit69plc0m0af1g,signature=BFA4B8F006B99D40D693C48EC213371247D13A27850ED00ECFC23567123FD27FB1259D34DF50D240E1B99308821B758187CEA2DDF531B8D47F2B257768C89A07,timestamp=1547040437
Customer-Ip 192.168.1.1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Test standard
accept application/json
```

Can any one please help me to resolve time out error with HttpwebReuqest

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Perhaps try adjusting the `Timeout` property.

Comment: @bolkay the default value of the `Timeout` property is set to 100'000 milliseconds or 100 seconds. I think there's a bigger problem if the API takes longer than that to answer

Comment: @MindSwipe: API is working fine with Soap UI and Postman but it gives error with C# code HttpWebRequest . I think this is due to some proxy but same things working with RestSharp third party library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got alternative solution, Using RestStarp Version 105.2.3 its working fine. Older version of restsharp was not consistence but new version is working fine